# Is there a word for a "mapper" type in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I'm thinking of functions, lists, dictionaries and tables. Q/KDB has an interesting view of these objects all as different representations of an I/O table (the explicit key, value tabular representation of a function).

Is there a term for the set of these types?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the term you are looking for is 'Applicable Value'.
https://code.kx.com/q/basics/glossary/

When mapping we must also choose how to map, that is done with iterators:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/